# Android Calendar DTSTART and DTEND woes

Tags: android, calendar

I need to insert a calender entry in my Android app. Now I know I shouldn't be using this method, but still. And I'm sure I'm not the only one around... I've done quite an number of searches on stackoverflow and the Internet to get to where I am with my code today.

Thing is, the event shows up, but on a wrong date, like 1972. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
private void insertCalendar(int calChoice) {
    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    event.put("calendar_id", calChoice);
    event.put("title", "WOOT");
    event.put("description", "Wootification");
    event.put("eventLocation", "Wootness");
    event.put("allDay", 0); 
    event.put("eventStatus", 1);
    event.put("visibility", 0);
    event.put("transparency", 0);
    event.put("hasAlarm", 0);

    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.set(2011, 7, 27, 8, 0, 0);

    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.set(2011, 7, 27, 9, 0, 0);

    long startTime = start.getTimeInMillis();       
    startTime = startTime * 1000;

    long endTime = end.getTimeInMillis();
    endTime = endTime * 1000;

    event.put("dtstart", startTime);
    event.put("dtend", endTime);

    Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Why are you multiplying by 1000?

getTimeMillis already return milliseconds.

You appear to be overflowing by going past your date by a 1000 times.